# Chrome changing inline styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, inline

One of my clients presented me with a page that's not displaying properly and I can't figure out why.  The URL of the page in question is http://www.honeysucklehillfarm.com/fun-farm and if you view the page in Firefox (and IE, amazingly) it works fine, but in Chrome the three sets of rotating images are much smaller and squished together.  From what I can tell, Chrome is changing the inline style (set by the jQuery rorator, I assume) of the DIV "views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_food_on_the_farm_shows-block" to 45px x 46px instead of the 180x185 shown everywhere else.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might want to try clearing the 34 errors and 20 warnings found by the W3 validator (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.honeysucklehillfarm.com%2Ffun-farm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://www.honeysucklehillfarm.com/sites/all/themes/hshf/styles/style.css?m6v7zv, line 383 you have the code: `width:11.375;` This width is invalid, it should be either `px`, `em` or `%` value.

As [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) said, you should consider fixing the errors & warnings that come up, but without investigating for a long time, these kinds of errors might be your problem.

Why are there so many nested `<div>`'s though? That seems to be an excessive amount, which is screaming for errors to occur..!

Comment: Wow, good catch -- that did it!  You're right about the nested DIVs, I'm not thrilled with that either but they're created by the Drupal modules that drive the image rotators so they're out of my control, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ouch, bad Drupal! *finger wag*

Glad this helped though :)